# how to delete lines in txt file, according to other files' content, Python3

Tags: list, python-3.x, readfile

I have two txt-files (file_srs.txt and file_rm.txt)

The content of these two files are:

```
# content of file_srs.txt, note \n is a newline symbol
APPLE\n
PEAR\n
ORANGE\n
BANANA\n
MELON\n

# content of file_rm.txt
PEAR\n
BANANA\n
```

I want to delete the content in file_srs.txt based on the content in file_rm.txt. So in this example, I want to delete 'PEAR\n' and 'BANANA\n' in file_srs.txt and the resulting file is:

```
# resulting content in file_srs.txt
APPLE\n
ORANGE\n
MELON\n
```

In practical case, there can be hundreds of names in file_srs.txt and tens of names in file_rm.txt. So efficient method is necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first should read in the lines in the original `original.read().splitlines()` and assign this list to a variable. Note that this is different from `original.readlines()` as with a file containing:

```
APPLE
PEAR
ORANGE
BANANA
MELON
```

`original.read().splitlines()` returns `['APPLE', 'PEAR', 'ORANGE', 'BANANA', 'MELON']`

whereas,

`original.readlines()` returns `['APPLE\n', 'PEAR\n', 'ORANGE\n', 'BANANA\n', 'MELON']`

It is easier to work with the actual line string rather than the line string including the `\n` as it makes for easier comparison; there is no need to check if a (eg) `'BANANA\n'` has `\n` before comparing it to `'BANANA'`.

Then the data from the second file should be read in using the same method. Using the two lists you can make a new list (if you want to work with the lines you want to keep later on) or write straight to a new file:

Lets say `all_lines= ['APPLE', 'PEAR', 'ORANGE', 'BANANA', 'MELON']` and

`lines_delete = ['PEAR', 'BANANA']`

```
lines_to_keep = []
        for line in all_lines:
            if line not in lines_delete:
                lines_to_keep.append(line)
```

Then these lines can be written to a new (or the same) file:

```
with open("new.txt","w") as new:
    for line in lines_to_keep:
        line = line+"\n"
        new.write(line)
```

### Example program:

```
with open("original.txt","r") as original:
    all_lines = original.read().splitlines()

    with open("delete.txt","r") as delete:
        lines_delete = delete.read().splitlines()
        print(lines_delete)
        lines_to_keep = []
        for line in all_lines:
            if line not in lines_delete:
                lines_to_keep.append(line)

with open("new.txt","w") as new:
    for line in lines_to_keep:
        line = line+"\n"
        new.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most efficient solution in speed and you don't mind, that there will be wasted space, you can overwrite the lines of the words to delete (including the new line character) with for example spaces.

However, if you don't want to waste space, you have to overwrite the whole file, i.e. you have to load the content of file_srs.txt to the memory, delete there all words of the file_rm.txt and then you have to overwrite file_srs.txt with the new content that is in the memory, which is file_srs.txt without the words in file_rm.txt.